# Search all records in subform from main form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a button that can search locations in all records in a table in the subform.

But it seems to show all records that have the [Location] in them instead of only records with the specific location entered in the textbox.

But once I've done my search, I can't seem revert the form to the original clear state, so that I can go back to searching other things.

```vb
Private Sub StartSearch2_Click()
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "select * from [FormTable] where [Location]='" & Me.LocSearch & "'"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        Set Me.Recordset = rs
    Else
        MsgBox "No record found", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Sorry"
        Me.RecordSource = strOriginalSQL
    End If
    Me.LocSearch = Null
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to not change the Record Source of your form and instead set the Filter property.

- Set the Record Source to `FormTable`. You can do this in the form designer.
- Then set the Filter with

  ```
  Me.Filter = "Location='" & Me.LocSearch & "'"
  Me.FilterOn = True
  ```
- You can clear the filter with

  ```
  Me.Filter = ""
  Me.FilterOn = False
  ```

---

If you want to filter a subform, you can do this from the main form with

```
With Me!mysubform.Form
    .Filter = "Location='" & Me.LocSearch & "'"
    .FilterOn = True
End With
```

---

It is a good idea to escape any single quotes in the search string

```
Me.Filter = "Location='" & Replace(Me.LocSearch, "'", "''") & "'"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The clear filter does not seem to do anything for me. And the filtering itself does work but only if I search for a ItemCode/ItemName first then it filters in that instead of all records.

Comment: Clearing the filter should display all the records. I used this approach many times and it works. Of course you must not do the filtering the SELECT command anymore. As for the other problem I do not know what the different columns contain and how you did filter them. i many records have the same Location then you will still see many records after filtering.

Comment: The clear button now works. The way my form and subform works it doesn't show any records unless searched for by either ItemName or ItemCode. I am trying to make a button show all records only if they contain the specific Location.

Comment: You can also set a filter like "0 = 1" to show no records.